# drush updatedb on multiple sites

Tags: 7, drush

I have a multisite installation with common modules code (all modules are in sites/all/modules). When I update the modules, after that I need to update the database of each site with drush updatedb -l site.com
It is a time consuming task to do this for each site.
Is there a way to batch update the database in multiple sites?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe drush v4.4 and above support `drush @sites updb`.

Comment: thanks. is this @sites a kind of variable? are more @...things exist? where exactly in drush.ws site is this documented? I had a look and did not find. thanks

Comment: @john Perhaps you can post this as a separate question because I don't have a comprehensive list of these features of drush myself. The `@sites` was something I stumbled upon.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a script I wrote for different time consuming tasks to run on a multisite installation

### The file has to be in your `sites` folder.

The script will loop through all folders (except `all` and `default`) to run the command choosen on every sites based on their `settings.php` file

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get all Drupal sites
sites=`find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print | grep -v '/all$' | grep -v '/default$' | grep -v '\.$'`

echo "Choose the commande to execute : "
echo "1. update"
echo "2. put sites offline"
echo "3. put sites online"
echo "4. clear all cache"
echo "5. clear css+js cache"
echo "6. clear specific cache"
echo "7. install specific module"
echo "8. disable specific module"
echo -n "Input [1,2,3,4,5,6,7 or 8] ? "
read choice

if [ $choice -gt 6 ] ; then
  echo -n "Extension (module/theme) name ?"
  read ext
fi

# For each site, execute the command
for site in $sites
do
  echo ----------
  echo $site
  cd $site  
  if [ $choice -eq 1 ] ; then
    drush updatedb
  elif [ $choice -eq 2 ] ; then
    drush vset --always-set maintenance_mode 1
  elif [ $choice -eq 3 ] ; then
    drush vset --always-set maintenance_mode 0
  elif [ $choice -eq 4 ] ; then
    drush cc all
  elif [ $choice -eq 5 ] ; then
    drush cc css+js
  elif [ $choice -eq 6 ] ; then
    drush cc
  elif [ $choice -eq 7 ] ; then
    drush pm-enable -y $ext
  elif [ $choice -eq 8 ] ; then
    drush pm-disable -y $ext
  fi
  cd ../
done
```