# How to use Drush's concurrent execution capability?

Tags: drush, multi-sites

I am using Drupal multi-sites (single codebase, multiple sites/*). Along with this, I have started using Drush aliases to manage them:

```
$ cat sites/all/drush/aliases.drushrc.php
<?php
$aliases['localdev'] = array(
  'site-list' => array(
    'site1', 
    'site2',
    'site3',
  ),
);
?>
```

This allows me to easily perform actions on all sites:

```
$ drush @localdev cc all
```

>> *I've also just discovered that I can just use [@sites](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12852/drush-updatedb-on-multiple-sites), and forgo the drushrc file*.

Doing this, will execute "cc all" on each of my sites in series (one at a time).

I'd like to take this to the next level and try to run these commands on all sites *simulantiously*. I've been doing some reading, and am under the impression that Drush [does](http://drupal.org/node/628996) [indeed](http://drupal.org/node/1053072) support this. The [drush_invoke_process() function](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/includes!command.inc/function/drush_invoke_process/5.x) takes $backend_options, which can contain (from function documentation):

```
 *      'invoke-multiple'
 *        If $site_alias_record represents a single site, then 'invoke-multiple'
 *        will cause the _same_ command with the _same_ arguments and options
 *        to be invoked concurrently (e.g. for running concurrent batch processes).
 *      'concurrency'
 *        Limits the number of concurrent processes that will run at the same time.
 *        Defaults to '4'.
```

What I can't figure out, however, is **how do I actually use this from the Drush command line**. Is there an option I need to pass to Drush, or do I need to set something in a settings file?

Any info will be much appreciated - my curiosity is piqued!

## UPDATE

Based on the answers below, I was able to create a simple test that demonstrates Drush's behaviour, and draw some conclusions:

Drush's default behaviour when executing operations on multiple sites is to use concurrent processes:

```
$ drush @localdev ev "drupal_set_message(time()); sleep(5);"

Continue?  (y/n): y
site1             >> 1360512943      [status]
site2             >> 1360512943      [status]
site3             >> 1360512943      [status]
```

This is true even when not using aliases, and is also true when using Drush's built-in @sites alias. These two commands yield identical behaviour as above:

```
$ drush site1,site2,site3 ev "drupal_set_message(time()); sleep(5);"
$ drush @sites ev "drupal_set_message(time()); sleep(5);"
```

To change the number of concurrent processes (default is 4), the '--concurrency=N' option can be passed in the drush command. For example, if I want serial execution, I can set the number of concurrent processes to 1:

```
$ drush @localdev ev "drupal_set_message(time()); sleep(5);" --concurrency=1

Continue?  (y/n): y
site1             >> 1360513387      [status]
site2             >> 1360513393      [status]
site3             >> 1360513399      [status]
```

Comment: That's a very good summary; thanks for writing it up. It would be great if that info was in the Drush documentation somewhere. I opened an issue to capture that: http://drupal.org/node/1914224

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
drush @site1,@site2,@site3,@site4 cc all --concurrency=4
```

I'm not sure how concurrent it actually was; the last message about site1 came immediately after the first message for site2, and all other messages were printed sequentially.  I did not measure to what extent each cc operation happened concurrently, or to what extent the system might have just been cpu or i/o bound, but it did seem to be nominally working.

Comment: I am working with something similar to this and realized a handy way of doing things using the `@sites` command. However, one glitch with it is that if the site directory is a symlink, the command does not recognize it. in my case the symlink is to a dir outside drupal root so ls- l gives :`site_dir -> ../../sites/site/src`.. perhaps it's bug I can fix if you can point me to the code responsible of building thelist

Answer (score 1):

For single instance (without site-list):

```
<?php
$aliases['localdev'] = array(
  'invoke-multiple' => TRUE,
);
?>
```

For aliases with site-list array it will run concurently even...

**After below comments**, let's review code for drush_invoke_process:
*`//` - my comment, `/* ... */` - shortening provided code.*

```
<?php
function drush_invoke_process($site_alias_record, $command_name, $commandline_args = array(), $commandline_options = array(), $backend_options = TRUE) {
  if (is_array($site_alias_record) && array_key_exists('site-list', $site_alias_record)) {
    /*  $invocations[] - this array filled with command for each site in site-list. */
  }
  else {
    /* aliases not defined or site-list not found.  So $invocations filled by one item. */
  }
  return drush_backend_invoke_concurrent($invocations, $commandline_options, $backend_options);
}
?>
```

Next called:

```
<?php
function drush_backend_invoke_concurrent($invocations, $common_options = array(), $common_backend_options = array(), $default_command = NULL, $default_site = NULL, $context = NULL) {
  /* Here building command line happen for each site (invocation). */
  return _drush_backend_invoke($cmds, $common_backend_options, $context);
}
?>
```

Next will called:

```
<?php
function _drush_backend_invoke($cmds, $common_backend_options = array(), $context = NULL) {
  /* Some simulating code and fork code */
  if (array_key_exists('interactive', $common_backend_options) || array_key_exists('fork', $common_backend_options)) {
    /* Direct running (interactive or fork) */
  }
  else {
    // Concurrency set to 4 by default. So --concurency just override it by another value.
    $process_limit = drush_get_option_override($common_backend_options, 'concurrency', 4);

    // Next is main call, that run commands as concurent processes using proc_open and streaming:
    $procs = _drush_backend_proc_open($cmds, $process_limit, $context);

    /* Processing of result running of processes. */

  }
  return empty($ret) ? FALSE : $ret;
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify? Are you saying that when using a site-list, Drush will automatically execute the commands concurrently on all the sites? I'm confused because a Drush maintainer suggested that the default behaviour is serial execution http://drupal.org/node/628996#comment-2637008.

Comment: invoke-multiple is for running the same command on the same site with the same options and arguments multiple times.  You want --concurrency=N for running the same command on multiple sites. That is the intention, anyway; I did not test with @sites or a 'site-list', but you're straying outside of intended behavior, should that happen to work.

Comment: You are correct about --concurrency; if you run a command on multiple sites in debug mode without --concurrency and without --invoke-multiple, you can easily see that it is running all of the commands concurrently. But again, 'invoke-multiple' => TRUE does nothing, and setting it to 2 in a site alias would make all of your commands run twice.

Comment: 2greg_1_anderson: invoke_multiple setting will work if you dont' set alias or site-list...